# Git can't commit any removed files, why?

Tags: git

I've tried googling for answers, but I haven't found any similar. The problem is that Git, all of a sudden, started showing "No such file or directory" for any file I try to remove.

```
$ git rm file_to_remove
rm 'file_to_remove'
$ git commit -m "temp"
Can't open file_to_remove: No such file or directory.
Can't open file_to_remove: No such file or directory.
tail: file_to_remove: No such file or directory
fatal: pathspec 'file_to_remove' did not match any files
```

The repository is local only, that is, it hasn't been published anywhere.

Comment: Do you have any custom commit hooks?

Comment: what does `git status` look like?

Comment: @MladenIlić bypassing a pre-commit hook did the trick. I wonder if they could improve the error messages to warn the user about that. Something like "Check if there is a commit hook that could be causing the problem" or something like that.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. :) Yeah, I agree, It's probably that the commit hooks are so underused that no one really cares.